Sitecore form is not redirecting after implemented Content Security Policies
I'm working on Sitecore 9 where I have implemented CSP in Sitecore using web.config. After adding the CSP configuration in web.config file, the site is still working but I have one Sitecore form where I have implemented redirecting to another page and this redirection is not working anymore while submitting the form.
This configuration I have added for CSP in web.config:
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <remove name="X-Content-Type-Options"/>
    <remove name="X-XSS-Protection"/>
    <remove name="Content-Security-Policy"/>
    <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block"/>
    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff "/>
    <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://apps.sitecore.net; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.buzzsprout.com; img-src 'self' data: https://assets.buzzsprout.com https://bat.bing.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://cloud.typenetwork.com https://assets.buzzsprout.com; font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.gstatic.com https://cloud.typenetwork.com; child-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://player.brightcove.net https://www.buzzsprout.com; upgrade-insecure-requests;  block-all-mixed-content;"/>    
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

Console log
Refused to load the script 'script-uri' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "your CSP directive".

Has anyone had this problem or know how to fix it?

Can you see anything in the browser console being blocked by the csp that might be relevant to the form?

Add here console log if possible?

I have added logs for reference

Does the script-uri has same hostname as your website? Or maybe www missing or some other difference with the url of the page that the form is placed on?

I also Faced same issue when working on CSP configuration.The redirection problem with your Sitecore form may stem from your Content Security Policy (CSP) settings. CSPs, while enhancing security, can sometimes be overly restrictive, potentially blocking crucial functions like form redirects.
First, check the form node and ensure the Ajax checkbox is selected. This step alone may resolve your issue.

Hope this helps!!!

Thanks I appreciate your assistance. The issue has been resolved. -Praveen

You can set an identifier in the HttpContext, if a Sitecore Forms component is set on the page. To do that you need to first set an identifier in the HttpContext, that the Application_EndRequest can react to it and set the needed directive. This is done by adding an item to the current HttpContext in the main view of Sitecore Forms, the Form.cshtml like this.
var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
ctx.Items["Forms.Component.Active"] = "1";

In global.asax file, set the needed directive just if a Sitecore Forms component is set on the page. Here is the code.
if ("1".Equals(HttpContext.Current?.Items["Forms.Component.Active"]))
{
    Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Security-Policy");
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", [yourCspConfiguration]);            
}

With that you can ensure to set unsafe-inline only on pages which contain components (e.g. Sitecore Forms) that require the execution of inline-scripts. In every other page without Sitecore Forms components, the content security policy header is not touched at all.
Refer to this for more details.
Hope this helps.
